# Salvar MP3 em um diretório específico usando youtube_dl

Tags: python

Olá! Como dito no título, estou querendo **salvar o audio que irei baixar em uma pasta específica** da minha área de trabalho usando o youtube_dl, mas ainda não encontrei uma alternativa clara.

O diretório que eu irei usar no caso é esse: *C:\Users\jenka\Desktop\Trabalho\Sources*

**Alguém tem alguma solução?**

```
import youtube_dl
import pytube

videoORaudio = input('Deseja baixar em MP3 ou Video? [1] para MP3 e [2] para Vídeo. -> ')

if videoORaudio == '1':
   video_url = input("Coloque o link do vídeo abaixo: ")
   video_info = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().extract_info(url=video_url, download=False)

filename = f"{video_info['title']}.mp3"
options = {
    'format' : 'bestaudio/best',
    'keepvideo': False,
    'outtmpl': filename,
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192'
    }]

}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(options) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_info['webpage_url']])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem pelo menos duas formas de se fazer isso. Uma é usando o próprio módulo `youtube_dl`. Basta trocar o valor do argumento `outtmpl` de `filename` para `'PATH%(title)s'+'.mp3'`. Onde `PATH` é o endereço que você deseja salvar o arquivo. Ou seja, `C:\Users\jenka\Desktop\Trabalho\Sources`, no seu caso.

Uma outra forma é simplesmente mudar o diretório de trabalho de dentro do programa usando `os.chdir`

Para isso, adicione as seguintes linhas no topo do arquivo:

```py
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\jenka\Desktop\Trabalho\Sources")
```